# Ionic app / ios & android not loading images using dynamic url

Tags: ios, apache, cordova, ionic-framework, safari

I have a web server that protects images and only servers them via a dynamic url like this:

`/images/image_id=abc123`

Actual images are stored like this:

`/images/cars/acura/abc123/file`   with no extension on the filename.

Calling an image url in a desktop browser like this: `/images/id=abc123`  works and displays the image just fine.

But no image is shown in a mobile browser or hybrid app on ios or android. The error is `401 Unauthorized` so I assume that's a permission/ownership issue where the mobile app is not the same owner/group as a desktop safari browser.  Is it possible to  access these images then without changing folder ownership/permissions?

UPDATE:  It's actually intermittent. Sometimes the images show up in the app, sometimes they don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can try loading the URL with SDWebImage。

SDWebImag GifGub：https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 0):

Try using **SDWebImage**. It provides an asynchronous image downloader with cache support. It also has categories for UIImageView, UIButton etc.

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
```

You can get it from https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage. It provides background image decompression. Same URL is not downloaded several times and main thread is not blocked.

Comment: I look at the [cordova version](https://github.com/revolunet/cordova-plugin-sdwebimage) but not compatible with my project (Cordova 7.0.1)

Comment: Also just able to test android...same problem.